# Dedekind’s construction of the Reals help

Tags: real-analysis

I’m stuck interpreting this part of the construction from Rudin’s book:

[image]

In Step 4 for (A1) why does taking an $r’ \notin \alpha$ and an $s’ \notin \beta$ mean that their sum is strictly greater than the sum of r and s?

Comment: +1 for showing the relevant portion of the book. Context matters a lot here. However in order to make effective use of this site it would be best that you become proficient with mathjax and type all the math content using it instead of inserting an image. You may visit the [mathjax tutorial especially written for beginners](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilities: either ${r' \in \alpha}$ or ${r' \in \alpha^c}$ (since ${\alpha}$ is a partition of ${\mathbb{Q}}$). It's easy to prove that all rationals in ${\alpha^c}$ are strictly greater than rationals in ${\alpha}$. Likewise ${s' \notin \beta \Rightarrow s' \in \beta^c}$ is greater than every rational in ${\beta}$. This now trivially gives ${r' + s' > r + s}$ for ${r' \in \alpha^c,s' \in \beta^c, r \in \alpha, s \in \beta}$.

---

**How to prove that every element in ${\alpha^c}$ is greater than every element in ${\alpha}$**.

So, the cut axioms Rudin uses are:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
(1)&\alpha\neq \emptyset,\ \alpha\neq \mathbb{Q}&\\
(2)&p \in \alpha,\ q < p\Rightarrow q \in \alpha&\\
(3)&p \in \alpha\Rightarrow\ \exists\ r \in \alpha\ |\ r > p&
\end{array}
$$
${(2)}$ helps us prove this. Pick a rational ${t \in \alpha^c}$. Then if we had ${t \leq p}$ for some ${p \in \alpha}$, then by ${(2)}$ would tell us ${t \in \alpha}$, which is a contradiction (because ${t}$ cannot be in both ${\alpha}$ **and** ${\alpha^c}$).

It should also make sense, since you should think of these cuts as basically breaking the real rational line into two sections: a "lower" section, and an "upper" section. So it makes sense all the elements in the upper section are bigger than the elements in the lower section.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don’t see the ease of proving that all rationals in $\alpha^c$ are greater that all the rationals in $\alpha$. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: @Ash sure thing, no problem. I haven't actually seen Rudin's book, so I will need to find quickly what axioms he is using to make the proof, one moment

Comment: @Ash I have given a proof of this now in the edit

Comment: You are a godsend. Thank you so much for the explanation!

Comment: @Ash no problem!